# Converting a single CSV/TSV string into a Java object?

Tags: java, csv

Instead of converting an entire CSV file to an object, is there a simple API that takes in one csv or tsv string, and converts it to an object? The api's I've found so far are geared towards csv/tsv FIlE to list of objects.

Obviously I could just split the String and call a constructor, but was wondering if there was a clean api I could use.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're expecting here. For example, how would you determine which values map to which fields?

Comment: @CupawnTae SuperCSV for example you can pass in a mapper that automatically maps to fields. Very simple and easy. Unfortunately its geared towards files, and not single string!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv). It looks pretty similar to the other answers but seems to perform better than SuperCSV according to their [tests](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison).

Define your POJO (both the annotation and constructor seems to be necessary):

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "foo", "bar" })
public class FooBar {

    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    public FooBar() {
    }

    // Setters, getters, toString()
}
```

Then parse it:

```
String input = "1,2\n3,4";
StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
CsvMapper m = new CsvMapper();
CsvSchema schema = m.schemaFor(FooBar.class).withoutHeader().withLineSeparator("\n").withColumnSeparator(',');
try {
    MappingIterator<FooBar> r = m.reader(FooBar.class).with(schema).readValues(reader);
    while (r.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(r.nextValue());
    }

} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go with [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it is at least twice as fast than SuperCSV and has way more features.

For example, let's say your bean is:

```
class TestBean {

// if the value parsed in the quantity column is "?" or "-", it will be replaced by null.
@NullString(nulls = { "?", "-" })
// if a value resolves to null, it will be converted to the String "0".
@Parsed(defaultNullRead = "0")
private Integer quantity;   // The attribute type defines which conversion will be executed when processing the value.
// In this case, IntegerConversion will be used.
// The attribute name will be matched against the column header in the file automatically.

@Trim
@LowerCase
// the value for the comments attribute is in the column at index 4 (0 is the first column, so this means fifth column in the file)
@Parsed(index = 4)
private String comments;

// you can also explicitly give the name of a column in the file.
@Parsed(field = "amount")
private BigDecimal amount;

@Trim
@LowerCase
// values "no", "n" and "null" will be converted to false; values "yes" and "y" will be converted to true
@BooleanString(falseStrings = { "no", "n", "null" }, trueStrings = { "yes", "y" })
@Parsed
private Boolean pending;
```

Now, to read your input as a list of `TestBean`

```
// BeanListProcessor converts each parsed row to an instance of a given class, then stores each instance into a list.
BeanListProcessor<TestBean> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<TestBean>(TestBean.class);

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
parser.parse(getReader("/examples/bean_test.csv"));

// The BeanListProcessor provides a list of objects extracted from the input.
List<TestBean> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
```

To parse TSV files, just change the combination of `CsvParserSettings` &  `CsvParser` to `TsvParserSettings` & `TsvParser`.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this Api:
http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/

You can use annotations to convert your entities in CSV.

Comment: Thanks! By any chance do you have an example of converting a single string to an object?

Comment: Using JSefa, I think there is no way of going from a simple `String` to `SomeObject`. You always need to serialize or deserialize an Object for which you already have set the members according to your csv String. It seems...

Answer (score 0):

In the case of SuperCSV which you mentioned in a comment, you could pass it a `String` wrapped in a `StringReader`, i.e.

```
CsvBeanReader beanReader=new CsvBeanReader(new StringReader(theString), preferences);

beanReader.read(theBean, nameMapping);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing that for my first revision. I have a large file, which has different lines that need to be parsed into different beans. So I had code similar to that inside a for loop.

Comment: @AlbertLim Shouldn't all the rows in the CSV be of similar format (e.g. a CSV of employees that contains managers, CEO, and programmer)? There should be a base (employee) that all the rows conform to and you can build different objects (managers, CEO, and programmers) from the base.

Comment: @nevets1219 unfortunately, the files we get from our provider has mashed different types of information together. Each line corresponds to different classes altogether!

Comment: How would you know what mapping to use without reading the row?

Answer (score 0):

I was currently dealing with a similar issue. in my case I wanted to **import a single csv row at a time into a single pojo** as I was getting my data in the form of discrete single line websocket updates. at the end [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv) worked best for me as I didnt have to put everything into a list of pojos first.

here the code

```
String csvString="rick|sanchez|99"

private CsvMapper mapper=new CsvMapper();
private CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Pojo.class).withColumnSeparator('|');
private ObjectReader r=mapper.readerFor(Pojo.class).with(schema);
Pojo pojo=r.readValue(csvString);
```

for this to work you also ned to add the following annotation to your pojo

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"firstName","lastName","age"})
```

as far as I know its the only one that easily lets you parse a **single csv line into a single pojo** instance. obviously you could also do this over a constructor by hand but these libraries deal with with type conversions for you so its particularly useful if your pojo contains lots of different attributes